# how to have all data of particular column from database by one variable?

Tags: sql

I am working on some filters in an e-commerce site.
I am using this kind of method to find.

**sql**

```
select * from table where item1='$variable' && item2='$variable2';
```

Now if the user types something in item1 and leaves item2 empty then I want to have the result related to item1 only, automatically eliminating item2. Or something like item2 = 'all data' or any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the variable for NULL as part of the filtering, and if it's NULL, the second condition `$variable2 IS NULL` will evaluate to true, and the result from filtering by the first variable will be returned. If the variable isn't null, the filtering will take place.

```sql
//map it to your flavor of SQL
WHERE item1='$variable' AND ($variable2 IS NULL OR item2 = '$variable2');
```